# Play-silhouette: how to create roles on the fly?

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I would like to be able to create and delete some Silhouette role on the fly, for instance add a role Manager that is not hard-coded.

The only solution I see is to store these roles in a database.

Silhouette needs me to implement this:

```
case class WithRole(role: String*) extends Authorization[User, CookieAuthenticator] {
  def isAuthorized[B](user: User, authenticator: CookieAuthenticator)(
      implicit request: Request[B]
  ): Future[Boolean] = {
    myChekingIfAuthorizedFunction()
}
```

The problem is that I cannot inject my database into a case class. So the only workaround I found is this:

```
myChekingIfAuthorizedFunction(): Future[Boolean] = {
    val currentApp: Application = Play.current
    val injector: Injector = currentApp.injector
    lazy val dbConfProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider = injector.instanceOf[DatabaseConfigProvider]
    lazy val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    lazy val isInRole = new IsInRole(dbConfProvider, ec)
    isInRole.isInRole(1, user)
}

class IsInRole @Inject()(
    protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider,
    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext
) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[MyPostgresDriver]
    with RoleTableDefinitions {

  def isInRole(roleId: Long, user: User): Future[Boolean] =
    db.run(userRoles.filter(_.roleId === roleId).result) map { relations =>
      relations.map(_.userId).contains(user.uuid)
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that `Play.current` is called.

So, do you have any idea to avoid this? Or is there a github project that I didn't find that provide this feature?